# Given a large number of objects, is it better to create multiple forms in Designer for them, or use code to create the forms?

Tags: vb.net, forms

If I have a large number of classes, each similar to the other in certain aspects (they all share a common base class, but each does things differently), and I need to create Windows forms for each to allow easy changing of their values through a GUI, what's the best approach?:

1. Create one matching form for each object in VS' forms designer, Or
2. Use code to create the forms dynamically at runtime.

#2 makes the most sense to me, because a lot of these objects will share very common features of the form, notably "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons.  But one object might need to draw a textbox on the form while another might need to draw a combobox.  Not to mention, if I want to put icons on the "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons, I'd have to do this for each copy of the form in designer, and that sounds like it could get out of hand quickly.

But is drawing forms through code sane?  VS' forms designer is pretty sophisticated and designed to make life easier.  Am I wise to consider ignoring its functionality and diving into the trench warfare of forms design through code?

Is there a better way I'm not aware of?  Or are there examples of automating form creation based on an existing object's properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 2 is what I highly recommend.  You get to take advantage of all of the strengths of coding such as inheriting functionality.  Everything is also visible rather than buried in designer properties.

Invest in writing some helper classes and extension methods.  Anything that you can 'push up' do so.  The customisation of the base form to a particular derived class should be limited to just adding the specific fields in the desired layout.

I have this down to 1 method call per field (usually) to create a labelled field bound to the objects property, positioned nicely on the form.  Whether text, date, numeric up/down, dropdown (based on an enum) etc.  The form takes care of Ok / Cancel behaviour including telling the object to save changes or revert if the form is cancelled.

A great help is that I use a very good and complete set of third party components that include the basic edit controls and these are placed in a 'layout' control that takes care of positioning, groups etc.  No more fiddling controls into place and having to do it over and over whenever the form is changed.  As a bonus the layout control automatically scales and adjusts things as the form is re-sized by the user.  Plus the forms and controls are easily given any of a range of visual styles at the application level.

You could add attributes to the class properties and even do away with the explicit form customisation.  I haven't gone that far and probably won't.  Catering for every possibility needs a whole attribute system whereas in code you can always do something a little bit special if needed.

For anything more than a once off form I wouldn't use the form designer method.  If there is a large hierarchy of classes and you control the design then code is the way to go.  Hey - we are programmers so fiddling about with things one by one is not the game to be in.

The first time you need to make some widespread change you will be ahead.

Comment: Then #2 is the method I'll use.  What's the layout control you use that handles all the positioning, resizing, and skinning effects?  I mimicked something similar once in Access VBA where I had a base form and had code to tweak the specific controls on that base form to each derived class.  But it was a lot of code, especially the positioning elements.  I didn't even bother with dynamically resizing because the math was just too much.

Comment: Not sure about the attributes thing, either.  I haven't really utilized attributes or extension methods just yet in my project.  Got a few spots where they'd be applicable, just low on the priority list to investigate.

Comment: @Kumba: I use the DevExpress suite.  That includes all of the editor controls, grids, trees, and XtraLayout.  You will see demos on their site of how to use the layout control in design mode.  Suffice to say that you can do it all through code as well.  Not cheap but well worth it for producing professional standard applications.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I'm aiming to opens ource my work at some point, so I can't use closed-source toolsets.  Way too lazy to really care about mixing licenses and the like when that time comes around.  I'll have to investigate what controls MS gives me and see what makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: @Kumba: Ah, then a third party commercial library is out of the question.  Have a look at the MS FlowLayoutPanel and TableLayoutPanel controls.  I believe they have similar capability but have not used them myself.  There may be other open source options but this is outside of my experience.  Whatever the library or DIY solution, I'd still advocate for coding over designer fiddling.  Good luck.